# XSLT 1.0 - do not specify duplicates and conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

with the help of another forum I managed to remove duplicates in an XML using XSLT, unfortunately I can't get any further here.

Background: In my XML, duplicates are often output under the HeaderInformation node in HeaderText.
We have managed to solve this, but currently the HeaderText node MUST always be present under HeaderInformation. - which is not always the case...

I would like to add an extension (when?, if?, otherwise?,...) that this XSLT solution is only executed if the HeaderText node is actually present in the XML, otherwise everything should remain unchanged.

My XML with HeaderText

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SALESINVOICE>
  <Interchange>
    <Recipient></Recipient>
    <Sender></Sender>
    <CreationDate></CreationDate>
    <Test></Test>
    <Interchange_Control_Number></Interchange_Control_Number>
    <HeaderInformation>
 <HeaderText>
        <Qualifier>AAI</Qualifier>
        <Text>AAI10854</Text>
      </HeaderText><HeaderText>
        <Qualifier>DEL</Qualifier>
        <Text>DEL0854</Text>
      </HeaderText>
   <HeaderText>
        <Qualifier>AAI</Qualifier>
        <Text>AAI10854</Text>
      </HeaderText><HeaderText>
        <Qualifier>DEL</Qualifier>
        <Text>DEL0854</Text>
      </HeaderText>
      <OrigInvoiceNumber></OrigInvoiceNumber>
      <InvoiceType></InvoiceType>
      <InvoiceDate></InvoiceDate>
      <InvoiceNumber></InvoiceNumber>      
      <CustomerOrderReference></CustomerOrderReference>
      <SalesOrderReference></SalesOrderReference>
      <SalesOrderDate></SalesOrderDate>
      <PackingslipId></PackingslipId>
      <DeliveryDate></DeliveryDate>
      <Currency></Currency>
      <TaxExempt></TaxExempt>      
      <Contact>
        <Contact></Contact>        
      </Contact>
      <TermsOfPayment>
        <PaymTermDescription></PaymTermDescription>
        <DueDate></DueDate>
      </TermsOfPayment>
      <CashDiscountConditions>        
      </CashDiscountConditions>
      <WeightAndVolume>
        <NetWeight></NetWeight>
        <UnifOfWeight></UnifOfWeight>
      </WeightAndVolume>
      <SupplierAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>        
        <VATNum></VATNum>        
      </SupplierAddressInformation>
      <BuyerAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>
        <VATNum></VATNum>
        <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
      </BuyerAddressInformation>
      <InvoiceAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>
        <VATNum></VATNum>
        <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
      </InvoiceAddressInformation>
      <DeliveryAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>
        <State></State>
        <VATNum></VATNum>
        <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
      </DeliveryAddressInformation>
      <TransportDetails>        
        <DeliveryTerms></DeliveryTerms>        
      </TransportDetails>
      <LineItem>
        <Lines>
          <OrderLineNum>1</OrderLineNum>          
          <GTIN></GTIN>
          <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
          <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>          
          <Quantity></Quantity>
          <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
          <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
          <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>          
          <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
          <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
          <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
          <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
          <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
          <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
          <LineAmount></LineAmount>
          <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
          <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
          <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
          <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
          <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    <LineTextt>
   <Qualifier>LIN</Qualifier>
   <Text>2534</Text>
    </LineTextt>
        </Lines>
        <Lines>
          <OrderLineNum>2</OrderLineNum>          
          <GTIN></GTIN>
          <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
          <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>          
          <Quantity></Quantity>
          <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
          <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
          <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>          
          <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
          <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
          <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
          <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
          <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
          <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
          <LineAmount></LineAmount>
          <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
          <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
          <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
          <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
          <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    <LineTextt>
   <Qualifier>LIN</Qualifier>
   <Text>234</Text>
   </LineTextt>
        </Lines>
      </LineItem>
      <Totals>
        <InvoiceTotal></InvoiceTotal>
        <NetAmount></NetAmount>
        <VATAmount></VATAmount>
        <DiscountAmount></DiscountAmount>
        <AllowanceOrChargeAmount></AllowanceOrChargeAmount>
        <DueDate></DueDate>
        <VAT>
          <VATS>
            <Percentage></Percentage>
            <Type></Type>
            <BaseAmount></BaseAmount>
            <VATAmount></VATAmount>
          </VATS>
        </VAT>
      </Totals>
    </HeaderInformation>
  </Interchange>
</SALESINVOICE>
```

My XML without HeaderText

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SALESINVOICE>
  <Interchange>
    <Recipient></Recipient>
    <Sender></Sender>
    <CreationDate></CreationDate>
    <Test></Test>
    <Interchange_Control_Number></Interchange_Control_Number>
    <HeaderInformation> 
      <OrigInvoiceNumber></OrigInvoiceNumber>
      <InvoiceType></InvoiceType>
      <InvoiceDate></InvoiceDate>
      <InvoiceNumber></InvoiceNumber>      
      <CustomerOrderReference></CustomerOrderReference>
      <SalesOrderReference></SalesOrderReference>
      <SalesOrderDate></SalesOrderDate>
      <PackingslipId></PackingslipId>
      <DeliveryDate></DeliveryDate>
      <Currency></Currency>
      <TaxExempt></TaxExempt>      
      <Contact>
        <Contact></Contact>        
      </Contact>
      <TermsOfPayment>
        <PaymTermDescription></PaymTermDescription>
        <DueDate></DueDate>
      </TermsOfPayment>
      <CashDiscountConditions>        
      </CashDiscountConditions>
      <WeightAndVolume>
        <NetWeight></NetWeight>
        <UnifOfWeight></UnifOfWeight>
      </WeightAndVolume>
      <SupplierAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>        
        <VATNum></VATNum>        
      </SupplierAddressInformation>
      <BuyerAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>
        <VATNum></VATNum>
        <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
      </BuyerAddressInformation>
      <InvoiceAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>
        <VATNum></VATNum>
        <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
      </InvoiceAddressInformation>
      <DeliveryAddressInformation>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <Name></Name>
        <Street></Street>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <City></City>
        <Country></Country>
        <State></State>
        <VATNum></VATNum>
        <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
      </DeliveryAddressInformation>
      <TransportDetails>        
        <DeliveryTerms></DeliveryTerms>        
      </TransportDetails>
      <LineItem>
        <Lines>
          <OrderLineNum>1</OrderLineNum>          
          <GTIN></GTIN>
          <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
          <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>          
          <Quantity></Quantity>
          <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
          <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
          <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>          
          <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
          <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
          <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
          <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
          <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
          <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
          <LineAmount></LineAmount>
          <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
          <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
          <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
          <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
          <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>    
        </Lines>
        <Lines>
          <OrderLineNum>2</OrderLineNum>          
          <GTIN></GTIN>
          <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
          <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>          
          <Quantity></Quantity>
          <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
          <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
          <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>          
          <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
          <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
          <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
          <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
          <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
          <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
          <LineAmount></LineAmount>
          <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
          <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
          <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
          <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
          <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>    
        </Lines>
      </LineItem>
      <Totals>
        <InvoiceTotal></InvoiceTotal>
        <NetAmount></NetAmount>
        <VATAmount></VATAmount>
        <DiscountAmount></DiscountAmount>
        <AllowanceOrChargeAmount></AllowanceOrChargeAmount>
        <DueDate></DueDate>
        <VAT>
          <VATS>
            <Percentage></Percentage>
            <Type></Type>
            <BaseAmount></BaseAmount>
            <VATAmount></VATAmount>
          </VATS>
        </VAT>
      </Totals>
    </HeaderInformation>
  </Interchange>
</SALESINVOICE>
```

My XSLT

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="header_text" match="HeaderText" use="Text"/>
  <xsl:key name="line_text" match="LineText" use="Text"/>

  <!-- Identity-Template für die nicht explizit benannten Elemente -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="HeaderInformation">
    <HeaderInformation>
      <xsl:copy-of select="HeaderText[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="HeaderText[generate-id() =
                            generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="akt_key" select="Text"/>
        <xsl:variable name="akt_group" select="key('header_text', $akt_key)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$akt_group">
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:copy-of select="HeaderText[last()]/following-sibling::*[following-sibling::LineItem]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="LineItem"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="LineItem/following-sibling::*"/>
    </HeaderInformation>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Same Problem at "Lines" -> "LineText".

I hope that you can help me here please.

THANKS

LG Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is amend your template match to this, to check if a `HeaderText` node exists

```
 <xsl:template match="HeaderInformation[HeaderText]">
```

If `HeaderInformation` does not have a `HeaderText` then the identity template will match it instead, and so everything then remains unchanged.

Note, I am confused by these three lines

```
  <xsl:copy-of select="HeaderText[last()]/following-sibling::*[following-sibling::LineItem]"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="LineItem"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="LineItem/following-sibling::*"/>
```

It looks like you are trying to select everything after `HeaderText` but before `LineItem`. You then select the `LineItem` and then everything after that. But this is really the same as doing this:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="HeaderText[last()]/following-sibling::*"/>
```

As you have the identity template in place, doing `xsl:apply-templates` here is the same as doing `xsl:copy-of`. (And I am guessing for `LineItem` you actually have a template matching that, so that will take priority over the identity template).

Furthermore, your `<xsl:for-each select="HeaderText[generate-id() =
                            generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]">` statement, including its body, could actually just be simplified to this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="HeaderText[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="header_text" match="HeaderText" use="Text"/>
  <xsl:key name="line_text" match="LineText" use="Text"/>

  <!-- Identity-Template für die nicht explizit benannten Elemente -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="HeaderInformation[HeaderText]">
    <HeaderInformation>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="HeaderText[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="HeaderText[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="HeaderText[last()]/following-sibling::*"/>
    </HeaderInformation>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Having said that, there is an even simpler approach you can take, and that is rather than explicitly copy the distinct elements, think about removing the duplicate elements instead.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="header_text" match="HeaderText" use="Text"/>
  <xsl:key name="line_text" match="LineText" use="Text"/>

  <!-- Identity-Template für die nicht explizit benannten Elemente -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="HeaderText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You would have a similar template for `LineText` here also.

Comment: hey sorry, i found some other problem on my side.

if in my xml more articles (Lines) under LineItem, it should be possible that, the same texts are at article 1 and article 2. (the duplicate check shoul be on each line - not at lineitem)

the check for duplicates on line should be just check if there are duplicates on line not on the lineitem.

hope you can help me?

Comment: You should really ask a whole new question about this, as the original question was purely about duplicate HeaderText nodes. Thanks!